# How can I push the numbers inputted to check with the numbers on the page and execute the later parts of my code?

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to input 3 number into the input field. Once I click the button, I'd like to know if the number I inputted is the same as the "hidden" number (the number in white at first) on the page, and there will be further steps for the computer in the later parts of the code in JS. However, I can't do it right now with this piece of code. I'd like to ask what's missing for it not able to proceed?

Thanks a lot!

```js
let button = document.getElementById('button');
let no1 = document.getElementById('no1');
let no2 = document.getElementById('no2');
let no3 = document.getElementById('no3');
let ans = document.getElementById('Numbers');
let score = document.getElementById('Score');

window.onload = Ans();

function Ans() {
  var arr = ["012", "013", "014", "015", "016", "024", "025", "026", "027", "036", "037", "048"];
  var answer = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
  ans.innerHTML = arr[answer];
}

let a = ans.innerHTML;
let counter = 0;
score.innerHTML = counter;

function click() {
  if (no1.values == a.substring(0,1) && no2.values == a.substring(1,2) && no3.values == a.substring(2)) {
    ans.style.color = "black";
    console.log(a);
    a = "Congratulations";
    no1.value = "";
    no2.value = "";
    no3.value = "";
    counter++;
  }
  else {
    console.log(a);
    ans.style.color = "black";
    a = "Sorry! You are wrong!";
    no1.value = "";
    no2.value = "";
    no3.value = "";
  }
}
  
window.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
  if (ans.style.color == "black") {
    Ans();
    ans.style.color == "white";
  }
});
```

```css
#Numbers {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<div id="ans">
 <input type="number" id="no1" min="0" max="9">
 <input type="number" id="no2" min="0" max="9">
 <input type="number" id="no3" min="0" max="9">
</div>

<div id="btn">
  <input type="submit" value="Confirm" id="button" onclick="click()"/>
</div>

<div>
  <p id="Numbers"></p>
</div>

<div>
  <p>Score: </p>
  <p id="Score"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Need to change the funtion name to something other than `click`

```js
let button = document.getElementById('button');
let no1 = document.getElementById('no1');
let no2 = document.getElementById('no2');
let no3 = document.getElementById('no3');
let ans = document.getElementById('Numbers');
let score = document.getElementById('Score');

window.onload = Ans();

function Ans() {
  var arr = ["012", "013", "014", "015", "016", "024", "025", "026", "027", "036", "037", "048"];
  var answer = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
  ans.innerHTML = arr[answer];
}

let a = ans.innerHTML;
let counter = 0;
score.innerHTML = counter;

function mouse_click() {
  if (no1.values == a.substring(0,1) && no2.values == a.substring(1,2) && no3.values == a.substring(2)) {
    ans.style.color = "black";
    console.log(a);
    a = "Congratulations";
    no1.value = "";
    no2.value = "";
    no3.value = "";
    counter++;
  }
  else {
    console.log(a);
    ans.style.color = "black";
    a = "Sorry! You are wrong!";
    no1.value = "";
    no2.value = "";
    no3.value = "";
  }
}
  
window.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
  if (ans.style.color == "black") {
    Ans();
    ans.style.color == "white";
  }
});
```

```css
#Numbers {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<div id="ans">
 <input type="number" id="no1" min="0" max="9">
 <input type="number" id="no2" min="0" max="9">
 <input type="number" id="no3" min="0" max="9">
</div>

<div id="btn">
  <input type="submit" value="Confirm" id="button" onclick="mouse_click()"/>
</div>

<div>
  <p id="Numbers"></p>
</div>

<div>
  <p>Score: </p>
  <p id="Score"></p>
</div>
```